# Opinion about Android layout design to support multiple screens

Tags: android, layout, android-screen-support

I'm developing an Android app which needs to support phones and tablets (minSdk:14). By support I mean that layout and images (heights, widths, padding, margin, etc) should scale properly to different screen sizes. I don't need "different" layouts for tablets such as navigation drawer or rearranged layouts.

At first I tried creating layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp... but realized I was just duplicating layouts and only changing their measures (heights, widths, etc). I don't like this because it would be difficult to mantain in the future.

Instead I left all my layouts in the default /layout folder. I created several dimens.xml and place them in folders /values, /values-sw600dp etc.

For /values/dimens.xml I defined:

```
<dimen name="dp1">1dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp2">2dp</dimen>
...
<dimen name="dp100">100dp</dimen>
```

For /values-sw600dp/dimens.xml I defined:

```
<dimen name="dp1">2dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp2">4dp</dimen>
...
<dimen name="dp100">200dp</dimen>
```

As you can see, I doubled dps for tablets sw600.

Then I changed ALL my layouts measures (heights, widths, paddings, margins) to use "@dimen/..."

This way the layout seems to scale properly in all devices I tested on.
I would like some experts opinion on this design election.

1) Are there any problems with this approach?

2) Can you suggest better aproaches to acomplish the desired results?

Thank you!

Comment: You are doing it correct using values resources. Goal is nothing related to android but is related to general programming practices of preventing redundant code and a single place value change to reflect everywhere. Hope this helps  :)

Comment: Thanks @Javanator! SO won't let me mark your answer as accepted. Why?

Comment: It was a comment. I posted the same as answer below. You can mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it correct using values resources. Goal is nothing related to android but is related to general programming practices of preventing redundant code and a single place value change to reflect everywhere. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Andres, to explain android layout designs to support multiple screens you need to read [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Then also let me explain it here in brief, you need to create Multiple Drawables folder like Drawable-hdpi, Drawable-mdpi, Drawable-xhdpi, Drawable-xxhdpi and put same images with the same name in these 4 folders with the size of your requirements as per supported resolutions.

Then same way, you need to create multiple layout files to support multiple screens, remaining all the things will be handle by Android itself.

Comment: you need not to create multiple layout files if you can change the dimen in values folder resources. Thats much handy and is similar to like using styles. Single layout file with different styles for different screens

Comment: @Javanator At the end of the day all are working same way, if you create multiple files or give dimensions.

Comment: multiple files will have redundant code as Andreas Y already mentioned. In the end All works the same way always. But How smartly the same work has been done is a question here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use dimen file and drawble image in diffrent folder so you can design for all layout.

Everything about sizes and dimensions in Android
By Android Teacher on July 6th, 2013 in Appendix tags: android:textSize, dimen, dimens.xml, dip, dp, getConfiguration, getDimension, getDimensionPixelSize, getDisplayMetrics, hdpi, in, layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp, ldpi, mdpi, mm, pt, px, setContentView, smallestScreenWidthDp, sp, xhdpi, xxhdpi

Designing Android app you have to be aware of enormous variety of devices. They have different physical sizes (from small phones to large tablets), different screen sizes (diagonal from 3 inches or less to above 5 inches), different screen resolutions (from 320×480 pixels to Full HD – 1920×1080 – or more) and different screen densities – number of pixels per inch (from 120 dpi to 480 dpi). And there is also screen orientation (landscape or portrait) to take into account.
List of supported units:

dp or dip – density-independent pixels, abstract unit based on physical density of a screen

in – inches (not recommended)

mm – millimeters (not recommended)

pt – points, 1pt equals 1/72 of inch (not recommended)

px – pixels (not recommended)

You have to put unit after the value without space between.

For instance:


android:layout_width="120dp"
1
android:layout_width="120dp"
Measure units comparison in Android – only dp is universal (Android Studio)
Measure units comparison in Android – only dp is universal (Android Studio)

But what is easy in XML, it’s not so easy in Android Java. Though recommended unit is dp, Java methods use px as default. You have to do conversion on your own. First you have to check device scale ratio and then multiply it by dps you need (and add 0.5 to round it up). The result is float number that have to be change to int for measure methods.

This is an example (textElement is for instance TextView):


float scaleRatio = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dps = 100;
int pixels = (int) (dps * density + 0.5f);
textElement.setWidth(pixels);
float scaleRatio = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dps = 100;
int pixels = (int) (dps * density + 0.5f);
textElement.setWidth(pixels);
This is rather complicated so better define layout in XML or use… dimens.xml described below.

For text size use scale-independent pixels (sp)

When you define font size you could use all previously mentioned measure units. But there is one more unit created especially for text. It’s called scale-independent pixels (abbreviation “sp”). It’s very similar to dp, but have one more characteristic – reacts to user preferences about text size. In most cases sp equals dp, but if user want to scale text  it would allow to increase/decrease font without changing the size of other elements. So it’s recommended to use sp every time you refer to fonts.



<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_height">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textview_length">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="title_size">32sp</dimen>
</resources>
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_height">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textview_length">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="title_size">32sp</dimen>
</resources>
You could refer to them both in XML and in Java.

XML example:


android:layout_width="@dimen/textview_length"
1
android:layout_width="@dimen/textview_length"
Java example:


textElement.setWidth(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textview_length));
1
textElement.setWidth(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textview_length));
As you see in Java you have to refer to resources and use getDimensionPixelSize() method (that converts result to int, there is also getDimension() method that returns float value without rounding). Be careful as setWidth(R.dimen.textview_length) doesn’t show any error, but only because resources has int IDs. In this case you use ID value not value saved in dimens.xml.

There is one very useful effect of using getDimensionPixelSize() or getDimension(). They automatically convert dp or sp into pixels based on screen density. So you don’t have to do it on your own. If your text size is 16sp on mdpi screen it would have 16px, but on hdpi screen it would have 24 px.

Use many dimens.xml for various device types

Using dp and sp we have guaranteed ourselves that our layout would look the same on screens with different density. But usually we have much more space on 10 inch tablet than 4 inch phone. In the first case layout elements could be bigger.

To use various dimensions for different devices we could create separate dimens.xml files for them. Or to be more precise Android Studio already created them, so our aim is just to fill them with right values.

In project structure you could find values folders for smartphones, medium tablets and big tablets (Android Studio)
In project structure you could find values folders for smartphones, medium tablets and big tablets (Android Studio)

There are three values folders interesting for as: values, values-sw600dp and values-sw720dp-land. First one is mainly for smartphones, second for 7 inch tablets and third for 10 inch tablets (in landscape orientation). You could use just two of them: first for phone and second for all tablets.

In all of them you could find dimens.xml files (if not, just create them). This allows you to decide what size of objects and text would be on different devices.

For instance:


<!-- phones -->
    <dimen name="title_size">24sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_width">64dp</dimen>
<!-- phones -->
    <dimen name="title_size">24sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_width">64dp</dimen>

 <!-- small tablets -->
    <dimen name="title_size">32sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_width">80dp</dimen>
 <!-- small tablets -->
    <dimen name="title_size">32sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_width">80dp</dimen>

<!-- big tablets -->
    <dimen name="title_size">48sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_width">128dp</dimen>
1
2
3
<!-- big tablets -->
    <dimen name="title_size">48sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_width">128dp</dimen>
Dedicated layout files for various device types (and screen buckets concept)

Android creators introduced so called buckets to divide devices based on their screens parameters. There were defined four size buckets:

small – screens at least 426dp x 320dp (all smaller are scaled to it)

normal – screens at least 470dp x 320dp

large – screens at least 640dp x 480dp

xlarge – screens at least 960dp x 720dp.

If you want to address large device, you could create folder layout-large and keep there a copy of your layout files.

Unfortunately that concept didn’t work to good as in the large group you could have phones and small tablets that usually need different approach.

New concept is based on minimum available width in dp (for instance in case of 640dp x 480dp it equals 480 dp). There are now three standard selectors and related layout folders:

layout – for all devices with minimum width below 600dp (for instance 480×800 dp)

layout-sw600dp – for all devices with minimum width above 600dp (for instance 1024×600 dp)

layout-sw720dp – for all devices with minimum width above 720dp (for instance 1280×800 dp)



This allows you to create dedicated layout files for them.
```